# Passing props to a state to use in a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, schedule

Will preface that I have about 4 weeks of coding experience and so apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious.

I'm trying to pass an array of objects from Profile.js to Calendar.js, with Calendar.js currently ultimately being returned again in Profile.js. The idea's that a user would be able to set a schedule and be able to see the same schedule when they go back to the profile page. I was trying to get this to work by having the saved array of objects be displayed upon rendering the Calendar.js, but right now it basically resets itself every time the user goes back to the page.

Two issues I'm guessing are relevant here:

1. Initializing `this.state` to `this.props.calendar` isn't working (seems like `this.props.calendar` returns empty during initialization) but when I log `this.props.calendar` in the `handleChange` or `render()` it does show up correctly.
2. I believe `handleChange` runs whenever the page is clicked and so was thinking there might need to be some way for Calendar.js to display the old saved array of objects instead of an empty array (in case no schedule is selected at the time of click). Was trying to implement some kind of conditional operator here but `handleChange` currently stops working if it is called while a new empty schedule's selected (so if the user happens to click on the page before selecting a schedule).

This came out to be a bit longer than I expected, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Calendar.js:

```
export default class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schedule: this.props.calendar
    };
  }

  handleChange = newSchedule => {
    this.setState({ schedule: newSchedule.length !==0 ? newSchedule : this.props.calendar });
    this.props.handleSubmitCalendar(newSchedule); // call API function to save current selected schedule to a database
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScheduleSelector
        selection={this.state.schedule}
        ...code...
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Profile.js:

```
import Calendar from "../components/Calendar";

export default function Profile() {
  const [calendar, setCalendar] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoad() {
      try {
        const profileCalendar = await loadCalendar();
        setCalendar(profileCalendar);
      } catch (e) {
        onError(e);
      }
    }
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  async function handleSubmitCalendar(calendar) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      updateCalendar(calendar);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      onError(e);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  function loadCalendar() {
    return API.get("notes", "/calendar");
  }

  function updateCalendar(calendar) {
    return API.put("notes", "/calendar", {
      body: {calendar}
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="Calendar">
    <Calendar calendar={calendar} handleSubmitCalendar={handleSubmitCalendar}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! You should really read the React documentation and go through the examples. Everything you need to known to answer this question is in there and going through it all will make you a more competent developer and save you a lot of headaches. [Available here](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). If you still don't understand once you've gone through the docs, ask again here and I will help you.

Comment: Appreciate the help! I read through the main concepts in the documentation yesterday and realized the constructor was missing ```this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);```. However, now there's an issue where the scheduleSelector only loads once user clicks somewhere on the page, and then proceeds to click the scheduleSelector again. I think I'm not working with the scheduleSelector correctly, and on top of that realized ```this.props.calendar``` is returning as a blank object when it first gets passed into the constructor. Could you advise as to where this might be going wrong?

Comment: You haven't included the `ScheduleSelector` component in your example so I can't help there. As for `this.props.calendar` are you actually passing the calendar as props from the parent component? Try create a minimal example on codesandbox. You will consistently get better answers if people can quickly edit your code and it shows that you have put in effort on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! ```ScheduleSelector``` is something we're importing from here: https://github.com/bibekg/react-schedule-selector. Here is an example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/scheduleselector-gqdpf?file=/src/App.js. I think ```this.props.calendar``` is getting passed in, but maybe not before ```this.state``` in the Calendar.js initializes, which might be why it always initializes as blank. In codesandbox, the APIs don't actually link to anything which is why nothing gets saved, but in my local version it does save but with the odd quirk I mentioned in my last comment.